# Powerpoint - Resize image by different step

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

In powerpoint i want to get two images to be the same height without loosing their aspect ratio. 
However powerpoint only lets me resize an image in steps (eg when i drag the bottom left anchor of the image it resizes in jumps). Unfortunately this jump is bigger than the difference between the two images. Is there someway to resize them by a smaller amount?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> while dragging. It lets you adjust the size precisely.

Comment: Don't tell anyone. It's a secret ;)

Comment: meh! - wish i'd known that years ago ... also works for move it seems :)

Comment: Yep, it also works for moving.